# Using automake and configure with a toolchain

Tags: linux, compilation, cross-compiling, configure, automake

I'm trying to cross-compile some libraries which use `automake` and `./configure` but I can't get them working with my toolchain. I am setting the `--host` and `--build` flags (possibly incorrectly) and also the `CC`, `CPP`, `CXX`, and `CXXCPP` environment variables.

I see in the output of `./configure` that it's correctly picking up my toolchain compiler. I also see these lines in the output:

```
checking for i686-linux-objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
<...>
checking for i686-linux-strip... strip
checking for i686-linux-ranlib... no
```

Is `./configure` using the local hostmachine copy of `objdump`? Is it correctly finding `strip` in the toolchain under the name `i686-linux-strip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is ./configure using the local hostmachine copy of objdump?

Apparently.

> Is it correctly finding strip in the toolchain under the name i686-linux-strip?

Yes.